# Curving text using image magick

Tags: unix, image, imagemagick

```
system('  convert -size 320x100 xc:lightblue -font Candice -pointsize 72 \
           -fill navy -annotate +25+65 \'Anthony\' \
           -distort Arc 120  -trim +repage \
           -bordercolor lightblue -border 10  font_arc.jpg
');
```

curving text like arc

This code is not working please help me

Comment: Why don't you post the results you're getting?

Comment: I don't get the result so that i post the forum

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on your system there is no font with the name 'Candice'. Try with with 'Arial-Normal'.

Or select any font that is listed by this command:

```
convert -list font
```

In general, you should run these two steps to debug your problem:

1. Run the code on the commandline first and make sure it works there.
2. Translate this code into whatever programming language API you use.

This commandline works for me:

```
    convert                         \
       -size 320x100 xc:lightblue   \
       -font Arial-Normal           \
       -pointsize 72                \
       -fill navy                   \
       -annotate +25+65 \'Anthony\' \
       -distort Arc 120             \
       -trim                        \
       +repage                      \
       -bordercolor lightblue       \
       -border 10                   \
        font_arc.jpg
```